# in C# What is the best method for 2 parameters search without database

Tags: c#, arrays, search, dictionary

Function f(x,y)=z, using brute force I have all possible X and Y values within the search space and corresponding Z values (20K records).

I need to retrieve X,Y ( parameters) for maximum Z (yield) (X,Y,Z pre-calculated): "Select X,Y where Z is maximum"

From (1 performance 2 simplicity ) point of view ( no database ), which would be best method to follow :

- List of arrays
- Multidimensional Dictionary
- List/array of custom type
- table
- something else?

Comment: A sorted multimap z -> (x,y) seems obvious. Or just sorted array of (z,x,y).

Comment: If you hold triples `x,y,z` in some kind of collection, a simple thing is Linq's `.OrderByDescending(triple => triple.Z).First()` which will give you the `x,y,z` you want. But please post some code to make your question more concrete.

Comment: Or maybe you just want "foreach x in the range of x, foreach y in its range, calculate z=f(x,y), if z is greater than the 'record' until now, remember x y and this new record, and continue the double loop"?

Comment: Thank you, the values are pre-calculated, I should have omitted the Function from my question, but I thought it gives a better idea. Do you think Linq's will be optimal from performance (resources usage,speed) point of view?

Comment: Where are the pre-calculated values, and how are they kept?

Answer (score 0):

I kindly suggest that you should clarify your question. You should talk about search, only if the values are precalculated, in case of which, function f plays no role in your decision. Otherwise, if the values are not precalculated, then you are not talking about search, but for inversing the function f.

Anyway, if you are talking about precalculated values stored in a specific data structure, I would suggest some kind of a sorted collection type. I suppose the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z658b67%28v=vs.110%29.aspx could provide you with some usefull info.

Hope I helped!

Comment: Thanks for you post, I removed the word "Optimal- X,Y" and added "pre-calculated",hope it's more clear now

Comment: Since the values are precalculated, then linq is a nice hint (I would not suggest "for" loops). If you care for performance, like you should, the way the data is stored would have an affect on the proposed linq query. Therefore, I would suggest to write us a snippet of code showing the data structure where the data is already stored. Then we could suggest something more meaningful.